Temporary Visitor Visa for Japan - Should I give father's ITR?
I am planning to apply for a temporary visitor visa for Japan to visit my friend.
My personal savings are good enough {10L INR (11960USD)} and I am bearing all expenses for the trip on my own.
Still, is it a good idea to give my father's ITR? I think it might show good home ties and also give me backup for any unforeseen events.
I have a letter of invitation from my friend. Should I need to attach a letter of guarantee in this case (where I am bearing all the expenses)?
what are your thoughts?

@DavidRecallsMonica and I are both wondering what ITR means. Can you edit your question?

For a visitor visa, the supporting documents should show that you're tourist. Showing enough funds serves a dual purpose: it makes it likely that you can afford to be a tourist, and also that you have a good job (i.e. less likely that you're looking for a new job in Japan).
Since the typical tourist would not include their father's tax records, adding it would make your application stand out. That is not a good thing. It suggests that you think your application is not strong enough on its own merits. And if you yourself aren't convinced, then why should Japan be convinced?
For the same reason, a letter of guarantee is not as good as some people believe. If you're rich enough yourself, it's not needed. And if not, then is that person perhaps trying to find a better-paying job in the destination country? But for the case of Japan, see Guarantor's role in Japan's short term visa It's not so much a financial guarantee but more of a sworn statement. In your case, your friends statement will make your tourist intent more believable.

Thank you @MSalters for your detailed answer.
I have 2 years ITR with me but my one ITR is very low because that is for my part-time job (internship) and my current ITR is good enough. So in this case, is it good to give my father's ITR or should I consider giving my latest ITR only.

I get the impression that you are missing the central point of my answer. Including someone else's ITR is strange, weird. Japan will take a much closer look at your application because of it. They might even misunderstand, and think that you are trying to deceive them by pretending that your father's ITR is your own ITR. That is very bad: if you are ever denied a visa because Japan suspected fraud, you'll have major problems getting another visa ever, even for other countries. But a low ITR as a student? That is perfectly normal. No need to hide that.

What does "ITR" stand for?
